# Self Signed Certificate for a installer not working

Tags: c#, certificate

I'm a bit confused... I digitally signed my installer.exe file, but when I copy the file to a new computer and look at the properties it has a completely different certificate.

I ran this in powershell as admin and it gave me the thumbprint

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type CodeSigningCert -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Subject "CN=GreenSwamp Software" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.19={text}false") -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -KeyLength 2048 -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(33) -FriendlyName "GreenSwamp Software"
```

This i ran this with the thumbprint from above to create the pfx and this worked..

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String ????????-Force -AsPlainText 
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\DE67300F5009BFC86BB038C8F162BA2992FEEC8C" -FilePath "C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\GSSolution\Resources\Installer\GreenSwamp.pfx" -Password $pwd
```

Then to sign the exe with this...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\bin\i386\signtool.exe sign /f "C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\GSSolution\Resources\Installer\GreenSwamp.pfx" /p ????? /d "GreenSwamp Installer"  "C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\GSSolution\Resources\Installer\ASCOMGSServer10025Setup.exe"
```

looking at the exe properties it has the right digital signature.  But then I copy the exe to a new computer and look at properties and it's a different signature, not mine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it was a user error, but will leave the question because it explains the steps which do work.

Comment: But self-signed is still an invalid approach. You must buy a code sign certificate instead.

Comment: I believe the certificate can be installed in the local computer's trusted root and then the installer won't show the unknown publisher, and for future installs with the same cert.